# Is it possible to create External user profiles in IBM Connections using the ProfileAdminService?

Tags: ibm-sbt, ibm-connections

I've been able to create new profiles in IBM Connections 5 using the ProfileAdminService but can't find any documentation on how to flag them as External.

The Social business toolkit doesn't expose the isExternal flag via the Profile object.  I've tried to set it manually by 
profile.setAsString("snx:isExternal","true");
or
profile.setAsString("isExternal","true");

but the created profile always end up being a normal/internal one.

Is this possible yet via the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out over the weekend.

You CAN add external users using the connections ProfileAdminService  but you CAN't do it yet using Social Business Toolkit (functionality not there yet)

To make it work I created my own build of SBT and added "userMode" to the ProfileAttributes.  Caught me out initially as was looking for isExternal.  Should have guessed it was mode as that's the name in the TDI assembly

```
com.ibm.sbt.services.client.connections.profiles.utils.ProfilesConstants 

public enum ProfileAttribute {
            GUID("guid", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.guid"),
            EMAIL("email", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.email"),
            UID("uid", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.uid"),
            DISTINGUISHED_NAME("distinguishedName", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.distinguishedName"),
            DISPLAY_NAME("displayName", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.displayName"),
            GIVEN_NAMES("givenNames", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.givenNames"),
            SURNAME("surname", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.surname"),
            USER_STATE("userState", "com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.userState"),
            USER_MODE("userMode","com.ibm.snx_profiles.base.userMode") // <<<added this line
        ;
`
```